# Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab

I have installed GitLab on ubuntu but it's not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1WV3.png)
I have made changes in the gitlab.rb file for external_url and puma['port'] = 3333

Getting below error:

failed to load command: puma (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/puma)
2022-03-09_10:22:34.70826 Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3333

I have checked with command **sudo netstat -plnt | fgrep 3333**
below is the output:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1228947/nginx: mast

I think nginx is running on the same port, what are changes required to make in gitlab.rb file?
Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide your `gitlab.rb` configuration?

Comment: @sytech  Thanks for your response. I'm unable to post gitlab.rb file here. Everything is commented only 3 lines are active such as: 1) EXTERNAL_UR  2) puma['port'] 
 3) prometheus['monitor_kubernetes'] = false                                                                 
    Do I need to make more changes in the gitlab.rb file?